# How can we use sumiif function in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

We use Sumiif in excel and Google Sheets need.

Please let me know what is the function that we can use in google data studio instead of sumiif

Regards,
Girish

Comment: **Needs Details**: Share a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [TO-DO] that reproduces a specific issue, using sample data, showing 1) Input values [TO-DO], 2) Expected output [TO-DO] 3) An issue / attempt at solving the issue [TO-DO]). Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case and it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion & the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Issue, etc

Answer (score 1):

in Google Data Studio you would need to use the CaseWhen.
For example

SUM (Amount) WHERE (CASE WHEN Fruit = "Apple" AND Color = "Green" OR Color = "Red" ) then 1 else 0 END )